# Is it possible to table AUC output using gtsummary package in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using `auc` function from `pROC` package in R. Is it possible to use `gtsummary` package to put the results in table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to add the AUC. Below is an example adding it with the glance statistics from `broom::glance()`

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.0'

mod <- glm(response ~ age + trt, trial, family = binomial)

glance_with_auc <- function(x, ...) {
  df_glance <- broom::glance(x)
  
  # add AUC
  df_glance %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      AUC = with(broom::augment(x), pROC::roc(response, .fitted))$auc %>% as.numeric()
    )
}
glance_with_auc(mod)
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases
#> # A tibble: 1 × 9
#>   null.deviance df.null logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs   AUC
#>           <dbl>   <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1          229.     182  -113.  232.  241.     226.         180   183 0.576

tbl_regression(mod, exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  add_glance_table(include = c(nobs, AIC, AUC), glance_fun = glance_with_auc) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases
```

| **Characteristic** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 1.02 | 1.00, 1.04 | 0.095 |
| Chemotherapy Treatment |  |  |  |
| Drug A | — | — |  |
| Drug B | 1.13 | 0.60, 2.13 | 0.7 |
| No. Obs. | 183 |  |  |
| AIC | 232 |  |  |
| AUC | 0.576 |  |  |

<sup>Created on 2022-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can turn any data frame into a table with `gt::gt` on which `gtsummary` is based, so, using the `aSAH` data set from `pROC`, you could do, for example:

```r
library(pROC)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

aSAH %>% 
    filter(gender == "Female") %>%
    roc(outcome, s100b) %>%
  {data.frame(
    predictor = as.character(.$call$predictor),
    "Area under curve" = auc(.), 
    "Confidence interval" =
        paste(as.character(round(ci.auc(b), 2))[c(1, 3)], collapse = " - "),
    check.names = FALSE)} %>%
  gt()
```

[image]